# C# WPF Menuitem ItemsPresenter Template

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I have a context menu with that contains several menu items. One particular menu item ("In postfach kopieren") used to have many menu items as its children. The problem is that sometimes the number of children in the menu item "In postfach kopieren" is large and I wish to implement certain functionalities like Scrollbar and Search function. What I have done in my code is that I have added a grid as the child of menu item "In postfach kopieren". This grid has three children: 1) A text label. 2) A text block where the user can enter search text. 3) A scrollViewer. This scrollviewer has a Stackpanel as its content. And this stackpanel has several menu items (user lists) as its children. The functionality of this whole control seems to be working. But when I hover my mouse over the menu item "In postfach kopieren", it opens the popup and the hover effect is highlighted for the whole control. I only want the user list menu item to be highlighted and not the whole control.

I tried to test the mouse enter event of all the related controls (Grid, Stackpanel in the grid) etc. It is not able to disable to the hover functionality of the control.

```
    var cbtnPostfachKopieren = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();
cbtnPostfachKopieren.Header = "In Postfach kopieren";
cbtnPostfachKopieren.Items.Clear();
var grid = new Grid();
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(150) });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

var textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "Search";
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 0);
grid.Children.Add(textBlock);


var textBox = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
textBox.Width = 150;
textBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
textBox.Text = "Abishek";
Grid.SetRow(textBox, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(textBox, 1);
grid.Children.Add(textBox);

cbtnPostfachKopieren.Items.Add(grid);

var scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer
{
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible,
    Height = 100,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right
};

scrollViewer.Foreground = Brushes.Brown;
Grid.SetRow(scrollViewer, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(scrollViewer, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(scrollViewer, 2);
grid.Children.Add(scrollViewer);

var stackpanel = new StackPanel();
scrollViewer.Content = stackpanel;
            
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem _btnInPostfachKopierenUserInfo = new System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem();        
    _btnInPostfachKopierenUserInfo.Header = "Abishek Kumar JAin Ravikumar";
    stackpanel.Children.Add(_btnInPostfachKopierenUserInfo);
    _btnInPostfachKopierenUserInfo.Click += _btnInPostfachKopierenUserInfo_Click;
}
```

Atached is a screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ8mf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can so thos with a Control Templates for the MenuItem. Ther ist the yaml Code to Highlights the whole Item.

The easy way ist tot generate throug Visual Studio Designer the Templates Code fromm a MenuItem and change IT.

Comment: I only need to highlight the inner sub menu item with the header "Abishek Kumar Jain Ravikumar" and not the whole stackpanel. Can you please give me a general code example ?

Comment: I generated a template for menu item and assigned it to the menu item "cbtnPostfachKopieren ". 

var template = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as ControlTemplate; // Read template from file
cbtnPostfachKopieren.Template = template;

Doesn't seem to work